# Filter array with checkbox and input react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, filter, react-hooks

Hi guys i have filter function for a array i export from node i want to put 2 conditions before filter the object in my array 1 for check the universe of the character and one for the name. the filter work separetely but when i combine the two only 1 works. Here my code:

the filter function: filteredCharacter.

```
const SearchDisney = () => {

  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState('');
  const [btn, setBtn] = useState(false);
  const [apiResponse, setApiResponse] = useState([]);
  const [searchCharacter, setSearchCharacter] = useState('');
  const [searchUnivers, setSearchUnivers] = useState('');
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {

    callAPI();

    if (inputs.length > 2) {
      setBtn(true)
    } else if (btn) {
      setBtn(false)
    }

  }, [inputs, btn])

  const callAPI = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:9000/disneyCharacter")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => setApiResponse(res))
  }

  const handleInput = (e) => {
    setSearchCharacter(e.target.value)
  }

  const handleCheck = (e) => {
    setSearchUnivers(e.target.value)
    setChecked(e.target.checked)
  }


  **const charactersFiltered = checked === false && searchCharacter.length <= 2 ?
    (
      apiResponse
    )
    :
    (
      apiResponse
      .filter((character) => {
        return character.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchCharacter.toLowerCase())
      })
      .filter((character) => {
        return character.univers.toLowerCase().includes(searchUnivers.toLocaleLowerCase())
      })
    )**

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="search-result">
        <h1>Personnage Infos</h1>
        <SearchBox handleInput={handleInput} handleCheck ={handleCheck}/>
        <CharacterList className="search-result-display" charactersFiltered={charactersFiltered} />
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  )
}


export default React.memo(SearchDisney)
```

Here the search  Component:

```
<div>
  <input placeholder='Chercher votre personnage préféré' onChange={props.handleInput} type="text" />
  <form>
        <fieldset>
            <legend style={{color: 'white'}}>Chercher par univers</legend>
            <input
            type="checkbox"
            name="disney"
            value="disney"
            onClick= {props.handleCheck}
            />
            <label style={{color: 'white'}} htmlFor="univers">Disney</label>
            <input
            type="checkbox"
            name="starwars"
            value="starwars"
            onClick={props.handleCheck}
            />
            <label style={{color: 'white'}} htmlFor="univers">StarWars</label>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

and then list component:

```
const CharacterList =  (props) => {

  const characters = props.charactersFiltered.map((character, id) => {
    return <Character key={id} name={character.name} username={character.username} yearCreation={character.yearCreation} image={character.image} univers={character.univers}/>
  })

  return (
    <div>
        { characters }
    </div>
```

My problem is when i select the universe with the checkBox the search is launch automatically with 1 character but i want it search only if i put minimun 3 character in the input like I select starwars universe and i have to type minimun "Luk" in the input to search luke skywalker. But at the moment when i select starwars in the checkbox and type L in directly display luke but i want to have minimum Luk. I hope you understand me, any advice? Thanks !

Comment: when i do const charactersFiltered = searchCharacter.length <= 2 || checked === false   instead off : const charactersFiltered = searchCharacter.length <= 2 && checked === false  it do what i want but with that i can't search a character without select a universe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution i change my function filteredCharacter like this:

```
const charactersFiltered = checked === false ?
  (
    searchCharacter.length <= 2 ?
      (
        apiResponse
      )
      :
      (
        apiResponse
          .filter((character) => {
            return character.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchCharacter.toLowerCase())
          })
      )
  )
  :
  (
    searchCharacter.length <= 2 ?
      (
        apiResponse
        .filter((character) => {
          return character.univers.toLowerCase().includes(searchUnivers.toLowerCase())
        })
      )
      :
      (
        apiResponse
          .filter((character) => {
            return character.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchCharacter.toLowerCase())
          })
          .filter((character) => {
            return character.univers.toLowerCase().includes(searchUnivers.toLowerCase())
          })
      )
  )
```

and it works!